# Slow wifi after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 beta

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, beta, 22.04

I was on Ubuntu 21.10 and my WiFi connection was fast (more than 100Mbps). After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 (beta), it is now very slow (12Mbps max).

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: 18:d6:c7:1b:67:98
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.15.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7120000-f712ffff
```

Any idea?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *testing* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022

Comment: The comments above make sense but also want to add that I'm experiencing this as well.